# Консольное приложение (с использованием принципов объектно-ориентированное программирование) производство и бухгалтерский учет

Tags: c#

Вечер добрый. Хочу написать консольное приложение с использованием принципов объектно-ориентированное программирование **производство и бухгалтерский учет** но не используя базы данных т.к. я это еще не проходил. Это должно быть примитивное консольное приложение  *С чего мне начать?* За ранее спасибо.

Comment: Задача несет прикладной характер, или самообазование?

Comment: Начните с определения в каком формате хранить данные, для этого и читайте литературу

Comment: Думаю, вам сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/416584/10105

Comment: @Seyran и то и другое

Comment: @VadimProkopchuk - Я думаю что данные лучше будет если хранить в .txt формате

Comment: ну только не чистый txt, а хотя бы csv, он парсится нормально в таблицы и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даже не знаю с чего начать. Пожалуй с главного,  без Базы данных не получится. Поясню почему, БД в нашем деле, в двух словах, набор понятий (сущностей), данных, связей между понятиями и все это должно хранится на цифровом носителе. То что ты называешь БД и пока не хочешь использовать называется СУБД- Система Упрвления Базой Данных. Задача поставленная тобой является реализацией СУБД. Но боятся не стоит. 
Начнем с организации данных. В простейшем варианте хранилищем может служить txt файл, организованны,й как уже упоминалось, либо в формате, csv , может быть tsv, я бы посоветовал fwt - fixed width text file. Он удобен в плане разбора данных, зная структуру хранимого обьекта , можно легко серфить по файлу, считывать конкреные поля и т.д. Способ хранения - 1 сущность 1 файл. Для примитивного варианта сойдет если описание сущностей и связей будет в приложении, в идеале их тоже нужно выводить из логики приложения и описывать в БД. 
 Теперь о том что тоже важно, предметная область. Без ее понимания трудно будет посроить правильную ER модель, следствием будет мучительная переделка приложения. Совет, почитай пару статей по теме, необязательно с глубокими техническими деталями, в твоем случае теория даст больше информации к размышлению (деланию выводов, проведению параллелей со своей задачей). Пока столько, удачи.

Answer (score 1):

> производство и бухгалтерский учет

Слишком широко, объемно. Начните с так называемых "пользовательских историй". Представьте пользователя своей будущей программы, какие у него будут сценарии использования вашего приложения. Далее выявляете сущности, которые будут в модели приложения, какие у них будут свойства, как они будут связаны между собой. Затем можно на основе сценария использования и модели проектировать интерфейс приложения. Ну и приступать писать код. Данные программы можно хранить в виде xml или json, если вы не планируете использовать БД.